# How to return the client datas with contacts data and if clients don't have contacts return the clients data

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

At my application, I have two tables called `clients` and `contacts` and `clients` can have many `contacts` about this we can know that inside the `contacts` have the `client_id` and I would like to create a query to a specific route called `/clients/:id` that will return the clients data join with the all contacts this clients have. So I would like to return something

```
{
    client: [
     {
      name_client:...,
      email_client:...,
      telephone_client:....,
      contacts: [
        allcontacts
      ]
     }
    ]
}
```

But I not getting what I want and I found other problem that with this query

```
select
    distinct clients.id as client_id,
    clients.name as client_name,
    clients.email as client_email,
    clients.telephone as client_telephone,
    contacts.id as contact_id,
    contacts.name as contact_name
from
    contacts
 inner join
    clients
    on contacts.client_id = clients.id
where
    contacts.client_id = 'd9935b6d-0497-4a45-b472-ed3b4f85cd60'
```

If my client do not have the contact(s), will return an empty object, but I wouldn't this, I would like to return the client data.

[image]

Comment: Change your `inner join` to a `left outer join`.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Is it possible to return one time the clients data?

Comment: Try it.  You need to change the `where` clause to `where clients.client_id = ...`.  You will get one row with the `clients` information and `null` values in `contacts.id` and `contacts.name`.  I will put it into an answer for you.

Comment: @MikeOrganek I tried to use your query but not worked. Returned an empty object

Comment: Sorry.  I will fix it.  That was a dumb mistake on my part.  I had `clients` and `contacts` reversed in the `from` part.  It is fixed now.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Well played bro! Thanks. But... I have another question, is it possible to return the client data one time? Because if I have many contacts will return the same clients data much time. I am saying this about JSON format Like
```
{
  "client": [
   "client_id": "b1b7929e-d81f-499e-a7fb-70340ca0c888",
    "client_name": "Ricardo Aramujo",
    "client_email": "ricardoaramujo@gmail.com",
    "client_telephone": "",
    {
      "contact_id": "...",
      "contact_name": "..."
    },
    {
     "contact_id": "...",
     "contact_name": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219874/discussion-between-vagner-wentz-and-mike-organek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your query to this:

```
select distinct clients.id as client_id,
       clients.name as client_name,
       clients.email as client_email,
       clients.telephone as client_telephone,
       contacts.id as contact_id,
       contacts.name as contact_name
  from clients
       left join contacts
              on contacts.client_id = clients.id
 where clients.client_id = 'd9935b6d-0497-4a45-b472-ed3b4f85cd60'
```

The `left join` returns all matching `clients` rows (presumably only one) along with any `contacts` rows with a matching `client_id`.  If there are no such rows, then `contacts.id` and `contacts.name` will be `null`.

If you would like to have PostgreSQL construct a json document for you from this, then use `jsonb` functions to accomplish that for you:

```
with base as (
  select distinct clients.id as client_id,
         clients.name as client_name,
         clients.email as client_email,
         clients.telephone as client_telephone,
         contacts.id as contact_id,
         contacts.name as contact_name
    from clients
         left join contacts
                on contacts.client_id = clients.id
   where clients.client_id = 'd9935b6d-0497-4a45-b472-ed3b4f85cd60'
), aggregate_contacts as (
  select client_id, client_name, client_email, client_telephone,
         jsonb_agg(
           case 
             when contact_id is null then '{}'::jsonb
             else jsonb_build_object( 
                'contact_id', contact_id, 'contact_name', contact_name
             )
           end
         ) as contacts
    from base
   group by client_id, client_name, client_email, client_telephone
)
select to_jsonb(aggregate_contacts) as result
  from aggregate_contacts;
```

Using a `lateral join`:

```
select to_jsonb(q) as result
  from (select clients.id as client_id,
               clients.name as client_name,
               clients.email as client_email,
               clients.telephone as client_telephone,
               case
                 when jsonb_agg(x) = '[null]'::jsonb then '[]'::jsonb
                 else jsonb_agg(x)
               end as contacts
          from clients 
               left join lateral 
                    (select id as contact_id, name as contact_name
                       from contacts
                      where id = clients.id) x on true
         where client_id = 'd9935b6d-0497-4a45-b472-ed3b4f85cd60'
         group by clients.id, clients.name, clients.email, clients.telephone
       ) as q
```